# AngularJS template component not rendering variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My goal is to render a bar graph angularJs chart, using an angularjs component. So I need to use the binding, from the main controller in case of the data changes.

I have an angularjs controller , with an array called 'labels' like that :

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.router", "ngCsv" ,'ngSanitize','ui.bootstrap' ])

app.controller('AnalyseController',AnalyseController)

AnalyseController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function AnalyseController($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $http, $location, $window, $filter, $mdToast, $mdDialog, $sce, $state) {

 labels = ['Toutes','Carrefour','Intermarché','Leclerc','Super U ','Carrefour','Lidl','Intersport','Decathlon','Dia','Renault','Osiatis'];
}
```

Then, i am trying to access ' labels' from an angularjs component like this :

```
app.component('graphique', {
    templateUrl:'_commerciaux/views/include/graphique.html',
    bindings:{labels:'='},
    controller : [ '$http','$scope','$rootScope','toastr',function control($http,$scope,$rootScope,toastr){

        console.log(labels);

        this.labels = labels;
        console.log(this.labels);

         this.$onInit = function() {            
              this.labels = labels;
            };

   }]
})
```

Well, the console log shows nicely the labels, but there is no way to show this variable inside the template : it seems to be undefined . whats weird is that i see it inside the console .

[image]

I'm trying to generate a graph, it doesnt work either , but as soon as a i dont use the 'binding process' and set the variables directly inside the component, then it works !

This is my html template,  $ctrl.labels doesnt display, while it is set in the parent controller, and the component is supposed to bind it in a 2 way binding manner :

```
<div class="chart-wrapper analyse_graph"   >
    <canvas class="chart chart-line" chart-data="$ctrl.data" chart-labels="$ctrl.labels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="$ctrl.series" chart-options="$ctrl.options" chart-colors="$ctrl.colors" height="70"></canvas>    
</div>
<div>

     {{$ctrl.labels}} // NOT SHOWING !!

</div>
```

**TEST 1 :
I have changed my controller like this :**

```
  function AnalyseController($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $http, $location, $window, $filter, $mdToast, $mdDialog, $sce, $state) {

     $scope.labels = ['Toutes','Carrefour','Intermarché','Leclerc','Super U ','Carrefour','Lidl','Intersport','Decathlon','Dia','Renault','Osiatis'];
    }
```

but now, the console says : **ReferenceError: "labels is not defined"** , ( this message is coming from the component ) .  So , as long as i don't use $scope, it is working inside the console, but the template doesnt render binded variables ...

**EDIT 2 :** This is how i call the template , very simple :

```
<graphique ></graphique>
```

**EDIT 3 :** Just to let you know how the graph works nicely, as long as i set the variable directly inside the component, and remove the binding part  :

The component call inside HTML :

```
<graphique ></graphique>
```

The component itself :

```
app.component('graphique', {
    templateUrl:'_commerciaux/views/include/graphique.html',
    controller : [ '$http','$scope','$rootScope','toastr',function control($http,$scope,$rootScope,toastr){


        this.labels = ['Toutes','Carrefour','Intermarché','Leclerc','Super U ','Carrefour','Lidl','Intersport','Decathlon','Dia','Renault','Osiatis'];
        this.data = [[12,24,40,35,20,12,55,78,45,12,32,45],[10,15,30,35,12,15,70,24,25,10,47,25]];
}
```

The template :

```
<div class="chart-wrapper analyse_graph"   >
    <canvas class="chart chart-line" chart-data="$ctrl.data" chart-labels="$ctrl.labels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="$ctrl.series" chart-options="$ctrl.options" chart-colors="$ctrl.colors" height="70"></canvas>    
</div>
<div>

{{$ctrl.labels}}

</div>
```

NOTE : And yes, {{$ctrl.labels}} displays well, but as long as I try to pass labels with the 'bindings' part from the component, it doesnt work any more, The template doesnt display .

Unfortunatly, , if i can't solve this problem, i've got to use the old faschionned '$emit' and duplicate tons of graphs and  olds school controllers because the 'bindings' not working. Maybe it is because of the $scope syntax i'm using inside my main controller : it is maybe too old ..

**RESOLVED**
Hey ! I was using angularjs 1.68 , so i should have looked at this before :

https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/docs/guide/component

it is a few different than the lastest version !

So this is now my main view (please notice the 'as ctrl' who was missing):

```
<div ng-controller="AnalyseController  as ctrl" style="overflow:auto;max-height:1000px;">
```

next, in my main controller, i now set variables like this  :

```
this.labels = ['Toutes','Carrefour','Intermarché','Leclerc','Super U ','Carrefour','Lidl','Intersport','Decathlon','Dia','Renault','Osiatis'];
this.data = [[12,24,40,35,20,12,55,78,45,12,32,45],[10,15,30,35,12,15,70,24,25,10,47,25]];
```

Then my component, is looking like that now :

```
app.component('graphique', {
    templateUrl:'_commerciaux/views/include/graphique.html',
    bindings:{labels:'=',data:'='},
    controller : [ '$http','$scope','$rootScope','toastr',function control($http,$scope,$rootScope,toastr){

 // No vars or init there
})
```

and, finally, this is the component call inside my view, pleae notice the variables calls :

```
<graphique labels="ctrl.labels" data="ctrl.data"></graphique>
```

Finally, my template still reference $ctrl vars :

```
<div class="chart-wrapper analyse_graph"   > 
    <canvas class="chart chart-line" chart-data="$ctrl.data" chart-labels="$ctrl.labels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="$ctrl.series" chart-options="$ctrl.options" chart-colors="$ctrl.colors" height="70"></canvas>     
 </div>
 <div> 

{{$ctrl.labels}}

</div>
```

Thank a lot for you help ! Angularjs Is super TOP, my projet is version 1.6.8 , that is why it is different when talking about components !

[image: mygraph]

Comment: Is the parent controller part a component, or is it just a controller?

Comment: It is just a classic controller, not a parent controller, thank you

Comment: In the child, `this.labels` will be available in the `$onInit`hook. Don't reference it with `console.log(labels)` immediately, it won't be there and the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: But as you can see, the console is showing it when i'm not using $scope.labels, ok lets try ...

Comment: Consider making a simple fiddle, there are a lot of things that are missing (how do you call your component, the templates...).

Comment: I will delete my answer as others are using the answers to the comments to provide similar answers

Comment: Not really using your answer, the missing part is in the template, not in the controller

Comment: A live example would greatly increase our ability to help :)

Comment: Thank you, but simply create a controller with the $scope syntax, then try to pass some controller variables to a component using 'bindings', i bet it wont work, and the template wont display something. I have no account to create a live example

Comment: I do this practically everyday for a living lol I know it works, but there can be gotchas. You can look into `controller as` syntax if you want try to binding directly to the controller instead of `$scope`.

Comment: Where don’t you have an account? There are plenty of places to create live examples (jsfiddle, stackblitz, etc)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, finally solved and added my comment , have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using $ctrl syntax:

```
function AnalyseController($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $http, $location, $window, $filter, $mdToast, $mdDialog, $sce, $state) {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.labels = ['Toutes','Carrefour','Intermarché','Leclerc','Super U ','Carrefour','Lidl','Intersport','Decathlon','Dia','Renault','Osiatis'];
}
```

And for your template, you need to pass the parameter

```
<graphique labels="$ctrl.labels"></graphique>
```

---

If you are using $scope syntax:

```
function AnalyseController($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $http, $location, $window, $filter, $mdToast, $mdDialog, $sce, $state) {
    $scope.labels = ['Toutes','Carrefour','Intermarché','Leclerc','Super U ','Carrefour','Lidl','Intersport','Decathlon','Dia','Renault','Osiatis'];
}
```

And in the template

```
<graphique labels="labels"></graphique>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Lets try this ! Do i have to keep the 'bindings' part of the component initialisation part ?

Comment: Updated for both syntaxes

Comment: ReferenceError: "$ctrl is not defined" , please, then how do i show $ctrl.labels inside the template ?

Comment: The OP is using a plain controller for the parent - not a component controller, so I’m not sure `$ctrl` is a thing (for the parent) unless you use `controller as` syntax

Comment: At least I think that’s what OP meant by “classic controller”

Comment: As long as i set this.labels directly inside the component controller, the template is showing correctly the values, using $ctrl.labels , and the graph is showing too, but as long as i 'm trying to pass the variable from my simple controller, then, it only works in the console !

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, finally solved and added my comment , have a nice day